# In MarkLogic where Triple Indexes are stored, in Disk or Memory? And which is better in memory or in disk?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

In MarkLogic where Triple Indexes are stored, in Disk or Memory? And which is better in memory or in disk? Also how can we insert these triples as XML in DB?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean with on disk versus in memory? And can you also elaborate some more on the context? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? What are you using the triples for? etc..

Answer (score 1):

The answers that you are looking for are conveniently located in [The Semantics Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics)

*You should really get through some of this document as a primer*. It will help you immensely. In the meantime, to address a few of your questions:

**Related to Where Stored:**
As a standard operation, MarklLogic stores the bulk of triple information on disk in a special index. Because of that, there is little initial memory usage - but of course, there are in memory caches(2) for performance of semantic operations and some parts of the triples stores mapped to memory.

There is, however, a way to create a triple store in memory (which you may wan to do for some special circumstances). This would be by using the function [`sem:in-memory-store()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem:in-memory-store)

**Inserting Triples:**
*Triples need not be in a document you manage*

- You can insert them using functions
- You can insert them by parsing standard RDF data formats
- You can insert them via REST
- Probably a  few more options

Yes, you can also create them and store them in your documents. This can be an extremely efficient solution in some use cases because the triples are stored in the same fragment as the document. That makes for some fun queries.

A great document is available here: [Managed vs Unmanaged triples](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/managed-vs-unmanaged-triples).

Comment: Thanks! But can you please tell me which function will work here? Like can we pass the SPARQL query result as parameter for any fucntion and insert all the triples with some collection name?

Comment: I gave you quite a bit of information to get you going.  The second document referenced has examples. If you need specific examples, please open a SO question with clear use-cases and describe what you have tried and where you need assistance.

Comment: I have crated TDE to generate triples from XML which is there in ML DB. Now I want insert these triples as XML in ML DB. Also it should be stored as Triples in ML DB so that we can query using SPARQL. I have tried to insert these using xdmp:document-insert. Which has worked but this is not inserted as Triples these are just XML.

Comment: This is the code which I am using ...for $c at $count in fn:collection("RULES") 
for $triples in tde:node-data-extract(fn:collection("RULES")[$count])
 let $xmltriple := json:transform-from-json( $triples)

return
xdmp:document-insert(fn:concat("/Triplel/Synonym/",$count,".xml"),$xmltriple,
            <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
            <collections>
              <collection>Rule Concepts Synonym</collection></collections></options>)

Comment: No one is likely going to follow up with assisting you with more questions in the comments... Add your details clearly (code, generated xml, etc.) In your original post or add separate SO  questions.....